# Getting the number of existing connections in WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

Is it possible to check the number of existing available connections a wcf service has? programmatically?

I want to see if connections to the web service were closed properly in the ASP.NET code.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check out something like [Windows Server AppFabric](http://blogs.technet.com/appfabric/archive/2010/01/20/monitoring-applications-using-windows-server-appfabric.aspx) for that purpose.

In WCF, most of the time, the "connections" are only open very briefly anyway - for as long as a service call lasts. So you can't really go check if there are any connections around - they'll be gone when the call terminates.

You can also check into the [WCF performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx) that are available on the server side to keep an eye on the number of concurrent sessions. You can definitely query performance counters from .NET code. The [Service Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731087%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) offer e.g. a number of instances (of your service class) that are in memory at any given time - that's the number of requests being handled at any given time (which is probably what you could call a "connection" to a WCF service).

Comment: +1 for the performance counters part. Those can be inspected by perfmon as well as queried from code.

Comment: Note that number of instances does not necessarily equal the number of requests. The InstanceContextMode setting can throw that off. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx

Comment: I knew about the performance counter but wasn't aware that it can actually tell you the number of instances. Thanks!

Comment: @mwilson: true - but it's probably the closest to the "number of connections" you can get using perf counters

Comment: Do you know of a way to monitor outgoing connections to a wcf webservice?

Comment: @UriAbramson: by default, WCF services are based on a "per-call" system, e.g. your clients don't have a connection that stays open for a long period of time (like a database connection might). So you can't really measure "outgoing connections" - you just have a number of concurrently ongoing requests at any given time.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the answer. i was talking about wcf Webservices. they do have a keepalive option for http connections don't they?

Comment: wsHttpBinding keepalive is set to True by default from what i know.. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/rotemb/archive/2008/08/04/how-to-change-wcf-keepaliveenabled-to-false-for-ws-or-basic-http-binding.aspx

Comment: @marc_s If the client is creating its own channel factory and they don't close it then wouldn't the connection still be around?

Comment: @BVernon: whether or not the client creates its own channel factory shouldn't be relevant - what is relevant is the mode of operation. If you're using the recommended *per-call* mode, you only ever have a connection very briefly - for the duration of the service call to handle your request. Unlike an ADO.NET database connection - there's no "connection" in WCF that remains open after a call.