# How to limit number of opened downloads for a specific file on server?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted on a server and another console application on multiple clients. Each console application send a request to download a specific file on server and I want to check how many downloads are currently active if more than 4 I want the WCF to deny the request if less then send the file. I don't know what is the best solution to detect the number of active downloads.

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776380/getting-the-number-of-existing-connections-in-wcf

check this it will be useful

Comment: @Gokuldas.Palapatta Thanks but this question asks for connections to WCF and it can't help me because when a client is downloading a file there is no connection between the wcf and client the wcf connections are closed briefly after a call is made

Answer (score 2):

You can use Service Throttling of WCF.
It can limit the number of concurrent calls:

[serviceThrottling at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can also program your own control, marking the service as Single, like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

And control the number of files with a static variable. It's not so clear but works.